# No se aplica el flexbox y esté bien

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, flex

Ya apliqué el `display:flex` al **padre contenedor**, pero me sigue acomodando los *ítems* uno debajo del otro.

¿Alguien sabe qué puede ser?

```css
.contenidos-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenidos-menu">
  <!--ACA VAN LOS CONTENIDOS DE LAS MATERIAS-->
  <div>
    <a href="https://miel.unlam.edu.ar/">
      <i class="fas fa-book-open clasee"></i>
      <div class="texto-contenidos">Contenidos</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="https://miel.unlam.edu.ar/">
      <i class="fas fa-file-alt clasee"></i>
      <div class="texto-contenidos">Prácticas</div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: El código que expones si funciona, ¿puedes revisar de nuevo?

Comment: Hola, Lucía. Funciona, pero que te siga mostrando los elementos uno debajo del otro significa que deberías recargarlo sin el caché. Puedes recargar presionando las teclas `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `R` que surta efecto lo que has intentado hacer.

Answer (score 0):

El error proviene de la propiedad flex-flow. Esta es una propiedad atajo que engloba las propiedades flex-direction y flex-wrap.

Esto quiere decir que la propiedad flex-direction que has usado queda anulada por la flex-flow ya que la flex-flow que has usado tan solo da valor a la propiedad flex-wrap, entendiendo como nula la flex-position.

Tan solo tienes que quitar la propiedad flex-flow y ya se ponen uno al lado del otro.

¡¡Aquí te dejo el enlace a la documentación para que aclares los conceptos!!

[Flex-flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex-flow)

Un saludo!

Answer (score 0):

Buenas Lucia tal y como enseñas en el código habría dos formas de solucionar el error que te puede ocurrir.

Una de ellas seria usando la siguiente estructura:

```
.contenidos-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

O de la siguiente forma:

```
.contenidos-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
```

La propiedad `flex-flow:` es un atajo para las dos propiedades individuales `flex-direction:` y `flex-wrap`.

En esta página puedes informarte más sobre como trabaja esta propiedad.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/flex-flow

Comment: El detalle es que si pruebas el código, el mismo funciona, entonces habría que ver si quien pregunta no tiene problemas derivados de caché